# Can I get feedback on my failed binary search implementation?

Tags: javascript

My goal is to write an `indexOf` function that uses binary search to find the index of the element you want in an array.

My problem is that, writing a recursive solution, I always blow the call stack -- even in absolutely tiny arrays. My expectation is that binary search even in a non-tail-call-optimised language shouldn't blow the call stack for any array that isn't *monstrously* large.

In English/pseudocode, my thinking is

- Take a soughtValue and an arrayToSearch
- Let `middle` be the length of the array divided by 2, rounded down
- Let `currentValue` be whatever is in the middle of the array (aka `arrayToSearch[middle]`
- If the currentValue is the same as the soughtValue, return `middle`
- If the currentValue is smaller than the soughtValue, recursively call this function on the second half of this array
- If the currentValue is larger than the soughtValue, recursively call thisfunction on the first half of this array
- Eventually we will land on the correct value and return it

Here's how I write it in JS:

```
function indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch) {
    let middle = Math.floor(arrayToSearch.length / 2);
    let currentValue = arrayToSearch[middle];
    if (soughtValue === currentValue) {
        return middle;
    } else if (soughtValue > currentValue) {
        return indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch.slice(middle, arrayToSearch.length));
    } else if (soughtValue < currentValue) {
        return indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch.slice(0, middle));
    }
}

let x = indexOf("Sarah", ["Jennifer", "Sarah", "David", "Jon"]);
console.log(x); // expecting 1
```

Yet as I said before, stack overflow.

I've carefully re-read my textbook's explanation of binary search, and I looked up a Harvard Intro CS lecture on the algorithm. I'm confident I understand the idea of it and I'm fairly confident JavaScript is doing what I expect it to. I understand the concept of a stack overflow and why a recursive algorithm might trigger one.

Yet, re-reading my code over and over, I can't spot the point I've messed up and made a logic error.

If anyone could enlighten me I would really appreciate it because I've absolutely exhausted my own mental resources here and came up empty.

Comment: A binary search only makes sense when the array is sorted. If you sort your array first, your example works.

Comment: Also, your first slice should probably be `arrayToSearch.slice(middle+1)`. (No need to include the middle element in the recursive call, since you already know it's not the right answer.) Then you can add a base case for an empty array that returns, e.g., `undefined`, and you'll avoid having stack overflows when the input is invalid..

Comment: Even with these changes, your code won't return the right indexes. (It returns indexes into the smaller slice of the array instead of the original array.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments above, here's a complete working example. Significant changes:

1. Instead of slicing the array, I'm passing the original array with `start` and `end` indexes. This is one way to make sure the index you return is an index into the original array.
2. When I recurse, I make sure that the middle element is not included in the recursive call.
3. I have a base case that returns `-1` (like the behavior of most built-in `indexOf` implementations) when the portion of the array we're searching is empty.

And of course, per my first comment, I started with a sorted array, since binary search only works on sorted input.

```js
function indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch, start=0, end=(arrayToSearch.length-1)) {
    // base case for an empty array or otherwise failing to find the element
    if (start > end) {
        return -1;
    }

    let middle = start + Math.floor((end - start) / 2);
    let currentValue = arrayToSearch[middle];

    if (soughtValue === currentValue) {
        return middle;
    } else if (soughtValue > currentValue) {
        return indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch, middle + 1, end);
    } else if (soughtValue < currentValue) {
        return indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch, start, middle - 1);
    }
}

let input = ["David", "Jennifer", "Jon", "Sarah"];
console.log(indexOf("David", input)); // 0
console.log(indexOf("Jennifer", input)); // 1
console.log(indexOf("Jon", input)); // 2
console.log(indexOf("Sarah", input)); // 3
console.log(indexOf("NOT THERE", input)); // -1
```

**UPDATE**

FYI, functions like this can easily be written iteratively rather than with recursion. In this case, I think I like the iterative version better:

```js
function indexOf(soughtValue, arrayToSearch) {
    let start = 0;
    let end = arrayToSearch.length - 1;

    while (start <= end) {
        let middle = start + Math.floor((end-start) / 2);
        let currentValue = arrayToSearch[middle];

        if (soughtValue > currentValue) {
            start = middle + 1;
        } else if (soughtValue < currentValue) {
            end = middle - 1;
        } else {
            return middle;
        }
    }

    // not found
    return -1;
}

let input = ["David", "Jennifer", "Jon", "Sarah"];
console.log(indexOf("David", input)); // 0
console.log(indexOf("Jennifer", input)); // 1
console.log(indexOf("Jon", input)); // 2
console.log(indexOf("Sarah", input)); // 3
console.log(indexOf("NOT THERE", input)); // -1
```